# Redux-toolkit useMutation hook isUninitialized:true

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, redux-toolkit

I am developing an application but I have an proble. When I click on the submit button of the form in react js I send the post request through useMutation hook in redux-toolkit in the response the useMutation hook return the following response

```
{status: 'uninitialized', isUninitialized: true, isLoading: false, isSuccess: false, isError: false, …}
isError: false
isLoading: false
isSuccess: false
isUninitialized: true
originalArgs: undefined
reset: ƒ ()
status: "uninitialized"
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Here in response the `isuninitilize` is true and the `isError` and the `isSuccess` is false why its happning?

Comment: That response means that you did not actually initiate the mutation.  Your submit button isn't triggering the API call like you want it to.  You'll need to include the code from your component for use to see *why* you haven't sent anything.